# How can i append partial view result in to div?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a div id="comments"
in this i am displaying 10 comments at a time. 
when user want to view next comments, i have provided one button that will collect next 10 comments. for this next comment i have created partial view to display remaining 10 comments into another div morecomments.

My problem is when i am displaying next 10 comments its showing me all 20 comments but whole comments div is getting refreshed, how to prevent loading whole comment div.

My code is here:

```
<div id="comments">

 // Display Comments

 <div id="moreButton">
      <input type="submit" id="more" class="morerecords" value="More Post" />
 </div>

</div>

<div id="morecomments">

</div>
```

**Jquery::**

```
$('.morerecords').livequery("click", function (e) {
            // alert("Showing more records...");
            var next = 10;            
            var url = '@Url.Action("ViewMore", "Home")'
            var data = { nextrecord: next};
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                 $("#morecomments").html(result);
                 }
             });

        });
```

In above code i am getting 10 comments first time and when user click on **More Post** button it will show me above 10 comments plus next 10 comments. but whole div is getting refreshed.

What changes i have to do so that i can get user comments without affecting previous showing comments?

Suppose user having 50-60 post in his section then all comments should be display 10+ on More Post button click and so on...

How can i do that?

Comment: `$("#morecomments").append(result);` give this a go

Comment: What do you use to access your data? Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc.?

Comment: @tugberk: i am using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your records and put it in comment div... Your code should like this:

```
$('.morerecords').livequery("click", function (e) {
        var next = 10;            
        var url = '@Url.Action("ViewMore", "Home")'
        var data = { nextrecord: next};
        var older_records = $("#morecomments").text();
        $.("comments").append(older_records); //When you will get next record data, older data will be filled in comment div.
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
             $("#morecomments").html(result);
             }
         });

    });
```

Comment: `$("#morecomments").text();` shouldn't `.html();` be more reliable? as they may have tags in it, unless thats the desired result :)

Comment: $("#morecomments").text() method is used to get content of morecomment div. Check the code again. It is doing three works. 1. Read content from morecomment div. 2. Append them to comment div. 3. Write new comment to morecomment div. I thin it will work.

Comment: actually i am implementing this whole section like facebook, in this comment section user can post comments as well as video url also. when i am playing video in my comments section and viewing more post by click on button video stops playing.. i am getting remaining comments but it should not stop playing video or affecting comment div.

Comment: Then you should create different div for each comment in comment div. And add them dynamically. So that other will not be effected by this.

Comment: @AbhendraSingh: Thanks for your support.. I have created dynamic div for each new result... and its working perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in:

```
$("#morecomments").html(result);
```

.html("somevalue") *deletes* the content, then fills it with whatever parameter you supplied.
Try doing this:

```
$("#morecomments").html($("#morecomments").html() + result);
```

or even easier:

```
$("#morecomments").append(result);
```

I know this works if you're passing strings, and a partial view is basically a html string. I don't know if there will be any conflict issues with the tags brought along by partial views.
Either way, this is the easiest way to *add* to an element rather than *write over* it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework (which you do), you need to use something like below:

```
public JsonResult Get(
    //this is basically giving how many times you get the comments before
    //for example, if you get only one portion of the comments, this should be 1
    //if this is the first time, this should be 0
    int pageIndex, 
    //how many entiries you are getting
    int pageSize) { 

    IEnumerable<Foo> list = _context.Foos;
    list.Skip(PageIndex * PageSize).Take(pageSize);

    if(list.Count() < 1) { 
        //do something here, there is no source
    }

    return Json(list);
}
```

This is returning Json though but you will get the idea. you can modify this based on your needs.

You can use this way for pagination as well. Here is a helper for that:

https://bitbucket.org/tugberk/tugberkug.mvc/src/69ef9e1f1670/TugberkUg.MVC/Helpers/PaginatedList.cs

Comment: thanks for this solution but as of now i am not going to use pagination. coz i have to change my whole implementation..

Comment: This not for pagination. You would like to get the comments part by part right? this method ensures that you do not get the same comment again.